# How to get a simple HelloWorld App to run in Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am trying to go through a simple Youtube tutorial for Spring Boot.

I am on the second video and I cannot get my maven spring boot project to run(https://github.com/ishonowo/HelloWorldSpringBoot.git) .

I tried all that has been suggested on this forum for the error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
>           at com.infotech.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp.main(HelloWorldSpringBootApp.java:10)

and for

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.infotech.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp

but I cannot get it to work.

Comment: did you download or clone that entire repository, and its dependencies like `org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;`, then compile the application including all the dependencies in the classpath? the error message is saying the `org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication` library is not found in the classpath

Comment: Please check what's [off-topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic). When you are posting a question about code that isn't working as expected, you need to post the error message (you did that), the expected behaviour (from the context I guess you expect it to be able to run), and **the shortest code to reproduce the problem**. There's no code in the question, which makes it difficult to help.

Comment: I expect the code to print Hello Nigeria in the browser when I run the code.

Comment: I put all my code on GIT Hub in the link provided.

Comment: Could you tell me where I can download or clone the repository? I on added the info to my pom file.

Comment: Re-download by removing and adding the entry in pom. result is Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
 at com.infotech.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp.main(HelloWorldSpringBootApp.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 1 more

Comment: SpringApplication.class exists in org.springframework.boot under spring-boot-1.5.4.RELEASE.jar

Answer (score 1):

Remove **maven-jar-plugin** declaration and instead add **spring-boot-maven-plugin**.

```
<plugin> 
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId> 
      <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
</plugin>
```

maven-jar-plugin would need few other parameters like addClasspath, archive and manifest configuration.

As you are using spring-boot go with spring-boot-maven-plugin which will include all the configuration required to run the app.

Comment: I have done this. Now I get the error. Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/SpringApplication
 at com.infotech.app.HelloWorldSpringBootApp.main(HelloWorldSpringBootApp.java:10)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication
 at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
 at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:331)
 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
 ... 1 more

Comment: I am redownloading Spring Boot using maven. I will update you with the result.

Comment: Someone please help.

Answer (score 0):

I deleted the .m2 folder then upgraded the JDK to 10 and everything worked.

Comment: If you have found a solution to your own question, then mark it as answered so anyone who has a similar question can find your solution.